# Navigation bar and UIWebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am having some slight issue and trying to fix it but can't find the easiest answer towards it. I have a navigation bar, which is taking top pixels away, and hence the webview content last 44 px if I am not wrong goes under the bounce and hides the content. Hence the problem is that I have a submit button, and since it needs to be clicked, it goes under the bounce condition and doesn't let me select the button. Any quick solution to this problem will be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot so we can understand better what your problem is please :)

Comment: Ryan, the link have the image intact. If you notice there is a button, below which only can be seen when scrolls down. If i set the bounces to now, it doesn't even show the button at all. http://tinypic.com/r/t8172a/6 Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your UIWebView has the autoresizingMask set to be flexible in height and width. You can do that in interface builder or in code.

Comment: The autoresizingMask definitely worked for me. Thanks for bringing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the bottom content insets to 44. But it seems your view is not put correctly (web view size does not take navigation bar into account, web view is not resized properly, etc.) I would fix that instead of patching with the insets fix.